# Generating a SAML assertion for a user using a different user login in OpenAM

Tags: openam

We currently have an api secured through OpenAM and SAML assertions.

However we need to 'integrate' with Salesforce. I don't want to federate ID providers with Salesforce so my API needs to:
1) Decrypt signed request from Salesforce to retrieve user id (email)
2) Using a specified user, login into OpenAM, retrieve user profile. 
3) ??? Generate SAML assertion for the retrieved user id.???
4) API works as before.

If this is not possible, I in effect, have to either bring session management into an API or possibly even have to different routes for the same functionality but with two different security models.

Comment: The terminology isn't quite right in your post: signed requests cannot be decrypted; requests don't contain user ID (did you mean responses?). I assume your API is playing the role of an SP, and AM is the IdP. Do you have to introduce SalesForce as a second IdP and be able to access your API by accounts coming from either AM or SF?

Comment: Hi, I have the Salesforce App secret so can decrypt the SF user id (email) that is passed from the SF canvas to my application. My API is the SP with AM being the IdP. You are correct that introducing SF as a second IdP is the approach I would have taken however for business reasons they do not wish to do this. So I need a way of taking the SF user id, handshaking with AM to generate a SAML assertion for the SF user id as 'trust' that the method through which I received the SF user id is good enough. (Note this approach does make me cringe).

Comment: If your API accepts SAML assertions signed by OpenAM, then you don't have a choice.